# Laravel ORM many to many relation with conditions on keys

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, relationship

I have a `members` table like this:

```
------------------
| id | name | ...
------------------
   1   John
   2   Jane
   3   Bill
```

and a `relations` table to store their relationship.

```
----------------------------
| from_id | to_id | status |
----------------------------
   1          2     friend
   2          3     friend
```

first records says: member#1 and member#2 are friends.
`member#1 is friend with #2` And `member#2 is friend with #1`.

in Laravel, How can I have a relation to get all friends of a member?
I need to check both columns `from_id` and `to_id` , and with this syntax in my `Member` model I can't get it.

**Member Model**

```
public function friends(){
    return $this->belongsToMany('Member', 'relations', 'from_id', 'to_id' );
}
```

*this only returns records that member_id is `from_id`*

*I want to have this query , if member = 1*

```
SELECT * FROM relations WHERE from_id = 1 OR to_id = 1
```

any help?

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, this is not the right answer to my question by Using Laravel ORM, but I'm using this and it produces the same result. I hope if someone else knows the correct answer share us here. thanks.

Define this method in `Member` model:

```
return Member::join('relations', function($join) use($limit) {
            $join->on('relations.from_id', '=', 'members.id')
                ->orOn('relations.to_id', '=', 'members.id');
        })
        ->where(function($where){
            $where->where('relations.from_id', '=', $this->id)
                ->orWhere('relations.to_id', '=', $this->id);
        })
        ->where('members.id', '!=', $this->id)
        ->groupBy('members.id')
        ->get();
```

So I can use:

```
$member = Member::find(1); // for example user#1
$member->friends(); // a list of eloquent objects of members.
```